# Mongoose date format when using find

Tags: date, node.js, find, mongoose

I have the following data in a mongo database:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4edbf890385eb606681a0262"), "ExternalId" : "7408364", "StartDate" : "12/02/2011 1:00 -05:00", "EndDate" : "12/02/2011 2:00 -05:00" }

and when I type the following query in the mongo command line tool I get results back:

db.schedule.find({'StartDate':{$gte:'12/02/2011', $lte:'12/03/2011'}});

My issue is actually with the mongoose npm module and the query portion of the find method.  Assuming Schedule is my Model, I've tried the following and have received no results:

```
    Schedule.find({'StartDate' : {$gte : '12/01/2011', $lte : '12/01/2011'} },
    function(err, schedules) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.contentType('application/json');
        res.json(schedules);
    });
```

And I've also tried the following with no results:

```
    Schedule.find({'StartDate' : {$gte : new Date('12/01/2011'), $lte : new Date('12/01/2011')} },
    function(err, schedules) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.contentType('application/json');
        res.json(schedules);
    });
```

I have tried numerous other formats but I can't seem to get any results back.  I know I must be missing something obvious being a rookie to mongoose and node in general.

Comment: You're searching "between" `'12/01/2011'` and `'12/01/2011'`, is that correct?

Comment: Note that the Date constructor expects the month parameter/2nd parameter to start from 0. I.e., 0 = january, 1 = februari, etc.